# How to set javascript variable to static json data?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to set the latitude, longitude to JSON values,

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long =position.coords.longitude;
```

And I am trying to set that variable to below code ,can you help me how do I do that?

```
var nooGmapL10n={"lottitude":+lat+,"longitude":+lons+}
```

It shows some errors, Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use [JSON Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to get `json` string.

Use code below to form json via `JSON Object` :

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long =position.coords.longitude;
var nooGmapL10n={"lottitude": lat,"longitude": long};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(nooGmapL10n);
```

To form json string without `JSON Object`(not recommended approach) use next code:

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long =position.coords.longitude;
var nooGmapL10n='{"lottitude":' + lat + ',"longitude":' + long + '}';
```

After performing code above you would get desired json represantation of your object.

**Update** Recommended some additional fixes in comments to that answer.

Comment: No,I texted "long" only,And when I inspect and get page source it shows `nooGmapL10n={"lottitude": lat,"longitude": long};`but it should show `nooGmapL10n={"lottitude":15.25478,"longitude":16.25488};` like that right..

Comment: That's because in first case your json string in `jsonData` variable. To get it into `nooGmapL10n` update `jsonData = JSON.stringify(nooGmapL10n);` to `nooGmapL10n = JSON.stringify(nooGmapL10n);`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation);
            function foundLocation(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var long = position.coords.longitude;`
        }
 </script>'

Comment: `var nooGmapL10n={"latitude":lat,"longitude":long,"maxZoom_MarkerClusterer":"20","zoom":"12","default_label":"","fullscreen_label":"","no_geolocation_pos":"The browser","no_geolocation_msg":"Geolocation",   "markers":[{"latitude":"19.0759837","longitude":"72.8776559","image":"<img src='1.jpg' class='attachment-property-infobox' alt='' />","title":"Sa","area":"Muai.","ww":"<span class='shop-location'>sss</span>","url":"1.html","location":"calif","sub_location":"green","status":"sales","category":"single","icon":"1.png"}],"ajax_finishedMsg":"All"};var nooGmapL10n = JSON.stringify(nooGmapL10n);`

Comment: Problem in your code, replace `function foundLocation(position) { 
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude; 
} `   to   `var lat, long;function foundLocation(position) { 
lat = position.coords.latitude;
long = position.coords.longitude; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

I notice some typos and corrected them as well. Try this:

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;

var nooGmapL10n={ "latitude": lat, "longitude": long }
```

Comment: if you want to send with JSON, you should use var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(nooGmapL10n)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nooGmapL10n={"lottitude":+lat+,"longitude":+lons+}
```

should be replaced by:

```
var nooGmapL10n={"lottitude":lat,"longitude":lons}
```

without "+" because `nooGmapL10n`is not a string but an object ;)